# How to write a number on a TShape Component?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a TShape Component. I need to load it dynamically and **I need to place a number on that TShape**. If anyone knows the way - please suggest it to me.

Thanks **Rakesh**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Canvas property of the [`TShape`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ExtCtrls.TShape) component to draw the number, to access this protected property you must create descendent class of TShape and publish that property or just use a [interposer class](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/handbook_note_67.html).

```
type
  TShape = class(ExtCtrls.TShape); //interposer class

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Shape1: TShape;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Shape1.Canvas.Font.Name :='Arial';// set the font 
    Shape1.Canvas.Font.Size  :=20;//set the size of the font
    Shape1.Canvas.Font.Color:=clBlue;//set the color of the text
    Shape1.Canvas.TextOut(10,10,'1999');
end;
```

Comment: Hi RRUK...I am not getting Canvas property of TShape.Is that property available..?

Comment: please read the answer carefully, the canvas is a protected property check this line  `TShape = class(ExtCtrls.TShape);` in the sample code.

Comment: I think its `TShape = class(vcl.ExtCtrls.TShape);`

Answer (score 2):

Place a TLabel above it and make its background transparent (Transparent = True). Edit text alignment if needed (Alignment := taCenter)